# How to distinguish oracle NUMBER(X) and FLOAT(126) DbTypes from schema in ADO.NET / C# 2.0

Tags: c#, ado.net, schema, types

I use oracleclient by creating DbProviderFactory and get schema:

```
DbDataReader reader = cmdForSchema.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);
DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
```

however both float and number have DbType.Decimal as their DataType in in schemaTable. At least we're using NUMBER for integers and it would be nice to know which is it?

I think I remember that there's a way to get provider specific types. But that has a downside as well since it's not general any more (e.g. for SqlServer).

Thanks & BR: Matti